# Store remaining numbers after sample() function

Tags: r, random, vector, sample

```
score = c(22,20,30,12,29,21,18,31,27,29,22,48,13,18,10,11,17,10,22,28,14,19,30,22,9)

x <- sample(score,size=13,replace=FALSE) 
y <- # I want y to store the numbers that were left behind after sample()
```

If I use the setdiff() function, it will remove all the duplicated number from the score list which is not what I'm looking for.

Can anybody give me some hints?

Answer (score 4):

Then don't sample the values, sample the indexes

```
score = c(22,20,30,12,29,21,18,31,27,29,22,48,13,18,10,11,17,10,22,28,14,19,30,22,9)

idx <- sample.int(length(score),size=13,replace=FALSE) 
x <- score[idx]
y <- score[-idx]
```